# Pycharm - How to sign in to git via Personal Token

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an existing Pycharm project, I created my local repo and then went to "Share project on github"

It then prompts me to login, of which I do, and this I get this error:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
                Successfully created project '' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
                remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
                remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
                Authentication failed for
```

Ok, well that makes sense, Password authentication is outdated, I'll just login via my token.
...

[image]

So, where do I do that?

Clicking on "Log In with Github..." only pulls back up the exact same page. Is there a hidden button somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/github.html#574dccf5)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to login with your *username* and a *token* instead of your password.
Follow the [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) here to create a token and then paste it in the password field.